# Can Inkscape be used for layout editing for photolithography?

Tags: layout, software

Inkscape is capable of [exporting DXF files](https://inkscape.org/en/about/features/), a format that is accepted by photolithography masks manufacturers.

Before I start working on layouts with Inkscape I would like to know if the exported DXF would actually contains all the information (layers, etc.) that is expected from a proper layout file such as GDS.

Comment: Your probably better off creating a quick layout and comparing the files.

Comment: I've tried using it for CNC work and got mixed results. DXF can get mixed up between CAD, Inkscape (and others) and CNC. Do a test file before sending money!